# how to read a list from a text file which is just below some text in python?

Tags: python, regex

This is a text file from which I have to extract the python list (starting from [{"WW":"WW18" ... ...  ) and them perform some operations on that list. how to do this?

```
Verified Title Successfully
6
Title of the graph Firmware Trend Status - AB - WW24.7
Title of the graph with categoryFirmware Trend Status - AB - WW24.7 
###########Firmware Weekly Status Value############
[{"WW":"WW18","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":45,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW19","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":25,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW20","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":35,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW21","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":45,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW22","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":55,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW23","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":75,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW24","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":65,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW25","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW26","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW27","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW28","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW29","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW30","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0}]
```

edit:
I tried the following code:

```
import re
import ast
fo=open(r"D:\Combined2345.txt","r")
s=fo.read()
data = re.search("\[.*?\]", s)
if data:
    print( ast.literal_eval(data.group()))
```

but it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/com12.py", line 7, in <module>
    print( ast.literal_eval(data.group()))
  File "C:\Users\2015s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\2015s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py", line 61, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "C:\Users\2015s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x07C9D230>
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regex` and `ast` module.

**Demo:**

```
import re
import ast
s = """Verified Title Successfully
6
Title of the graph Firmware Trend Status - AB - WW24.7
Title of the graph with categoryFirmware Trend Status - AB - WW24.7 
###########Firmware Weekly Status Value############
[{"WW":"WW18","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":45,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW19","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":25,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW20","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":35,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW21","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":45,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW22","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":55,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW23","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":75,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW24","Pass":0,"Fail":8,"Notrun":47,"Notready":0,"total":65,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":15},{"WW":"WW25","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW26","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW27","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW28","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW29","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0},{"WW":"WW30","Pass":0,"Fail":0,"Notrun":0,"Notready":0,"total":0,"passPerc":0,"runPerc":0}]
"""

data = re.search("\[.*?\]", s)              #Get content between []
if data:
    print( ast.literal_eval(data.group()))  #Convert string to list object.
```

**Output:**

```
[{'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW18', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 45, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW19', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 25, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW20', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 35, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW21', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 45, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW22', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 55, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW23', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 75, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 15, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW24', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 8, 'total': 65, 'Notrun': 47}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW25', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW26', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW27', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW28', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW29', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}, {'runPerc': 0, 'Notready': 0, 'WW': 'WW30', 'passPerc': 0, 'Pass': 0, 'Fail': 0, 'total': 0, 'Notrun': 0}]
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `Combined2345.txt`?

Comment: Following is the link for Combined2345.txt 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16eyedlsilnfECzD6OTkVD38YGg6jJh8f